# Ionic 2 custom config

Tags: cordova, ionic2

I'm building an ionic 2 app for multiple companies. Therefore, I need to be able to set multiple custom config values. These values are located in config.xml(for example: name/description), in the variables.scss(for example: primary/secondary color), and I have a custom configuration file holding server/database values.

What I want to achieve, is that every time I build this app for a new company, I just have to edit the values in 1 single config file, instead of 3 config files as it is in the current situation.

I have been trying to find a way to access config.xml values, without success. I have also tried setting the values of config.xml & variables.scss with my own custom config file, also without success.

Does anyone know how to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way for you to achieve this is using hooks. But i don't think it's possible for you to change scss via hooks and, even with it, you need to create config files por every action you want to do and change it before every build.

So maybe it would be easier if you develop a good architecture of your app that's easy to mantain and change the needed variables for every client.